# does anyone know what's the meaning of "busta straight busta"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms, slang, african-american-vernacular-english

I've playing a game called gta san andreas and in the second mission the character of the game says this sentence

> busta straight busta

according to the urban dictionary:

> A busta is somebody who ruins things, be it robberies at pizza places or attempting to follow a train.

Link: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Busta

And according to this website:

> The slang term “Buster” (also spelled “busta”) is a derogatory noun which is used by rappers in rap/hip-hop music to represent someone who is unpopular and weak.

Link: https://dailyrapfacts.com/17294/what-does-buster-mean/

but I still can't understand this sentence

my main doubt is

-Why he use the word "Straight" in this sentence?

Link of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dYWTiUndk0

Timestamp: (0:33)

Comment: Perhaps relate a few lines before this.  Who is the character talking to?

Comment: Urban Dictionary say a "busta" is [Someone who ruins everything](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Busta) - aka "asshole". And I'd buy "complete" as a reasonable synonym for "straight". So think *Asshole! Complete asshole!* when you read the reddit post [Busta !! Straight busta !!](https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/comments/10ls0nb/busta_straight_busta/) - *I met a kid outside the mall crying, he had lost his $200, so I gave him $40 from the $200 I found. When God blesses you, you must bless others.*

Answer (score 2):

Your question is: what does "straight" mean in this context? [As Wiktionary explains, "straight" can mean:](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/straight)

> (slang) Thorough; utter; unqualified.

It gives the example:

> ... they may even look like pimps, but they are straight simps.

This is the sense of "straight" being used here; it's essentially equivalent to the informal usage of "straight up."